# Storing and taking average of random number generated plots

Tags: random

I am working on a code which generates a number of random numbers which I have to use in a set of matrices. This set is then multiplied with some other matrix set in a particular order. And finally I have to plot one element of the resultant product matrix. But I have to generate random numbers for each run of the code and then after a numbers of runs I have to take the average. At this moment, I am running and plotting the data for each run of the code separately but this method is extremely time consuming as I have to do this 100 times! So I was wondering that is there a way that I can ask MATHEMATICA to save the resultant matrix element for each run on its own  and later on when 100 realizations of the code are completed then I recall all final matrices to take the average of the desired element? Below I am pasting a part of code for a single realization of random number generation and required plot:

```
TA = {{1 - I*β/(ωeg - δ), -I*β/(ωeg - δ)}, {I*β/(ωeg - δ),  1 + I*β/(ωeg - δ)}};

{L10, L9, L8, L7, L6, L5, L4, L3, L2, L1} = Sort[RandomReal[10, 10], Greater]
(* {9.63622, 9.3111, 8.82698, 7.81967, 6.85424, 2.93255, \
2.56615, 2.46661, 1.51094, 0.0989493} *)

TF1 = {{Exp[4*π*L1*I*δ], 0}, {0,  Exp[-4*π*L1*I*δ]}};
TF2 = {{Exp[4*π*(L2 - L1)*I*δ], 0}, {0, Exp[-4*π*(L2 - L1)*I*δ]}};
TF3 = {{Exp[4*π*(L3 - L2)*I*δ], 0}, {0, Exp[-4*π*(L3 - L2)*I*δ]}};
TF4 = {{Exp[4*π*(L4 - L3)*I*δ], 0}, {0, Exp[-4*π*(L4 - L3)*I*δ]}};
TF5 = {{Exp[4*π*(L5 - L4)*I*δ], 0}, {0, Exp[-4*π*(L5 - L4)*I*δ]}};
TF6 = {{Exp[4*π*(L6 - L5)*I*δ], 0}, {0, Exp[-4*π*(L6 - L5)*I*δ]}};
TF7 = {{Exp[4*π*(L7 - L6)*I*δ], 0}, {0, Exp[-4*π*(L7 - L6)*I*δ]}};
TF8 = {{Exp[4*π*(L8 - L7)*I*δ], 0}, {0, Exp[-4*π*(L8 - L7)*I*δ]}};
TF9 = {{Exp[4*π*(L9 - L8)*I*δ], 0}, {0, Exp[-4*π*(L9 - L8)*I*δ]}};
TF10 = {{Exp[4*π*(L10 - L9)*I*δ], 0}, {0, Exp[-4*π*(L10 - L9)*I*δ]}};
{{m11, m12}, {m21, m22}} = TF1.TA.TF2.TA.TF3.TA.TF4.TA.TF5.TA.TF6.TA.TF7.TA.TF8.TA.TF9.TA.TF10.TA;

m22;
t10a = 1/m22 /. {β -> 0.16, ωeg -> 1};(*α=k*L, δ is the plotting frequency*)
T10a = Abs[t10a]^2;
R10a = 1 - T10a;

Plot[{R10a, T10a}, {δ, 0, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.015], Red, Dashed}, {Thickness[0.015], 
    Black}}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Δ", ""}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 28}, 
 ImageSize -> {600, 500}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> Style["", FontSize -> 28]]
```

I shall be extremely thankful for help and sorry if I am asking something very basic as I am a beginner in MATHEMATICA.

Comment: You can shorten the code a lot by storing the 10 TF# and L# in a list and then compute the matrix `m` like so: `L = Sort[RandomReal[10, 10]];
TF = {{Exp[4 π # I δ], 0}, {0, Exp[-4 π # I δ]}} & /@ ({First@L}~Join~Differences@L); m = Block[{TA}, Dot @@ Riffle[TF, TA, {2, 20, 2}]]`

Answer (score 3):

As per my comment, this approach works:

```
TA={{1-I*β/(ωeg-δ),-I*β/(ωeg-δ)},{I*β/(ωeg-δ),1+I*β/(ωeg-δ)}};
Do[L = Sort[RandomReal[10, 10]];
   TF = {{Exp[4 π # I δ], 0}, {0, Exp[-4 π # I δ]}} & /@ ({First@L}~Join~Differences@L);
   m = Block[{TA}, Dot @@ Riffle[TF, TA, {2, 20, 2}]];
   T[i] = With[{β = 0.16, ωeg = 1}, Evaluate@(Abs[m[[2, 2]]]^-2)];, {i, 1, 100}]
```

Plotting is ridiculously long, but a quick look at the results is possible like so:

```
avg[δ_] = Mean[Array[T, 100]];
{#, avg@#} & /@ Range[0., 2., 0.05];
ListPlot@%
```

> [image]

A band structure can clearly be seen.

Update:
After this I started this code:

```
Do[pt[i] = {.001 i, avg@(.001 i)}; count = i;, {i, 0, 2000}]
```

and went for a coffee. When I came back, it was still running, so I aborted it and ran

```
count
(* 461 *)
ListPlot[Array[pt, 461]]
```

> [image]

Then I let MMA carry on with calculations like so:

```
Do[pt[i] = {.001 i, avg@(.001 i)}; count = i;, {i, 461, 2000}]
```

It'll get there eventually.

Update2:
After some time it's finally done, and, turns out, not much of a band structure there:

```
ListPlot[Array[pt, 2000]]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Using what you have already coded, first put them inside a module (You can shorten this part as suggested by `LLlAMnYP`).

```
  f[] := Module[{TA, L10, L9, L8, L7, L6, L5, L4, L3, L2, L1, TF1, TF2, 
  TF3, TF4, TF5, TF6, TF7, TF8, TF9, TF10, m11, m12, m21, m22, t10a, 
  T10a, R10a}, 
  TA = {{1 - 
  I*\[Beta]/(\[Omega]eg - \[Delta]), -I*\[Beta]/(\[Omega]eg - \
  \[Delta])}, {I*\[Beta]/(\[Omega]eg - \[Delta]), 
  1 + I*\[Beta]/(\[Omega]eg - \[Delta])}};

  {L10, L9, L8, L7, L6, L5, L4, L3, L2, L1} = 
   Sort[RandomReal[10, 10], Greater];


  TF1 = {{Exp[4*\[Pi]*L1*I*\[Delta]], 0}, {0, 
 Exp[-4*\[Pi]*L1*I*\[Delta]]}};
 TF2 = {{Exp[4*\[Pi]*(L2 - L1)*I*\[Delta]], 0}, {0, 
 Exp[-4*\[Pi]*(L2 - L1)*I*\[Delta]]}};
 TF3 = {{Exp[4*\[Pi]*(L3 - L2)*I*\[Delta]], 0}, {0, 
 Exp[-4*\[Pi]*(L3 - L2)*I*\[Delta]]}};
  TF4 = {{Exp[4*\[Pi]*(L4 - L3)*I*\[Delta]], 0}, {0, 
 Exp[-4*\[Pi]*(L4 - L3)*I*\[Delta]]}};
  TF5 = {{Exp[4*\[Pi]*(L5 - L4)*I*\[Delta]], 0}, {0, 
 Exp[-4*\[Pi]*(L5 - L4)*I*\[Delta]]}};
  TF6 = {{Exp[4*\[Pi]*(L6 - L5)*I*\[Delta]], 0}, {0, 
  Exp[-4*\[Pi]*(L6 - L5)*I*\[Delta]]}};
  TF7 = {{Exp[4*\[Pi]*(L7 - L6)*I*\[Delta]], 0}, {0, 
 Exp[-4*\[Pi]*(L7 - L6)*I*\[Delta]]}};
  TF8 = {{Exp[4*\[Pi]*(L8 - L7)*I*\[Delta]], 0}, {0, 
 Exp[-4*\[Pi]*(L8 - L7)*I*\[Delta]]}};
 TF9 = {{Exp[4*\[Pi]*(L9 - L8)*I*\[Delta]], 0}, {0, 
 Exp[-4*\[Pi]*(L9 - L8)*I*\[Delta]]}};
  TF10 = {{Exp[4*\[Pi]*(L10 - L9)*I*\[Delta]], 0}, {0, 
 Exp[-4*\[Pi]*(L10 - L9)*I*\[Delta]]}};
 {{m11, m12}, {m21, m22}} = 
  TF1.TA.TF2.TA.TF3.TA.TF4.TA.TF5.TA.TF6.TA.TF7.TA.TF8.TA.TF9.TA.\
  TF10.TA;

   m22;
   t10a = 1/m22 /. {\[Beta] -> 0.16, \[Omega]eg -> 1};(*\[Alpha]=k*
   L,\[Delta] is the plotting frequency*)
   T10a = Abs[t10a]^2;
   R10a = 1 - T10a;
    {R10a, T10a}]
```

The above function returns `{R10a, T10a}` each time it is executed for a random selection of all L#. Now we can run it `n` times and collect all the results. Find their mean and plot the results.

```
 plot[n_] := 
 Module[{allMatrix, allR10a, allT10a, mean1, mean2}, 
  allMatrix = Table[f[], {i, 1, n}];
  allR10a = Table[allMatrix[[i, 1]], {i, 1, Length[allMatrix]}];
  allT10a = Table[allMatrix[[i, 2]], {i, 1, Length[allMatrix]}];
  mean1 = Mean[allR10a];
  mean2 = Mean[allT10a];
  Plot[{mean1, mean2}, {\[Delta], 0, 2}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.015], Red, Dashed}, {Thickness[0.015], 
   Black}}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"\[CapitalDelta]", ""}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 28}, 
  ImageSize -> {600, 500}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLabel -> Style["", FontSize -> 28]] ]
```

For `n=100` it takes around 3 min on my system to generate the plot shown below.

```
 plot[100]
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you use `Module`, but proceed to define global variables within the module. That is not good _Mathematica_ coding style.

Comment: Are you referring to `mean1` and `mean2`  being defined as local variables in the second module?. You are suggesting that since these two variables are the final result that are plotted, they ought to be global? Now I have removed them from the local variable list.

Comment: No. I am suggesting that all the variables to which assignments are made to in your modules be localized.

Comment: OK understood and edited accordingly. Thanks and henceforth I will follow this practice.

Comment: Many thanks  LLlAMnYP,  Hubble07 and  m_goldberg  (especially the first two) for answering my question. That was indeed what I was trying to do...And I have learned new things from your reply.  Thanks again!                                                                                                  For belisarius has settled, MarcoB, Lou, blochwave, gpap: I don't know your reason for placing a hold as I tried to be as explicit and as clear as possible in asking this problem!